How to send a dictionary in post request in Nestjs when whitelist is set to true?
I'm trying to send a dictionary that maps a string key to an object. When whitelist is set to false I can get the data no problem, but when it is set to true I keep getting an empty body in NestJs. Currently data validation is not my priority, just trying to send the data to the backend.
How should I go about defining my DTO so the data gets passed correctly even when whitelist is set to true?
So far I have tried these two DTO variations.
This is the base DTO:
export class CreateBlogDto {
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @ApiProperty()
  title: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @ApiProperty()
  description: string;
}


And these are the DTOs that I'm having problems with:

try

@ApiExtraModels(CreateBlogDto)
export class CreateBlogTranslationsDto {
  @ApiProperty({
    type: 'object',
    additionalProperties: { $ref: getSchemaPath(CreateBlogDto) },
  })
  blogTranslations: { [languageCode: string]: CreateBlogDto };

}


try

@ApiExtraModels(CreateBlogDto)
export class CreateBlogTranslationsDto {
  @ApiProperty({
    type: 'object',
    additionalProperties: { $ref: getSchemaPath(CreateBlogDto) },
  })
  blogTranslations: Record<string, CreateBlogDto>;

}

This is how my endpoint looks like and in both the DTO variations it gets {} in the body:
 @Post(':blogId')
  async createBlogTranslations(
    @Param('blogId', ParseIntPipe) blogId: number,
    @Body() createBlogTranslationsDto: CreateBlogTranslationsDto,
  ) {
  }

To be more clear i want to send data like this to my post endpoint:
{
  blogTranslations: {
     "en": {
         "title": "English title",
         "description": "English description"
      },
     "es": {
         "title": "Spanish title",
          "description": "spanish description"
      }
   }

}


Simply add CreateBlogDto in @Body()

But that won't have the desired effect that i wan't. I don't want to send a single CreateBlogDto. I want to send a dictionary that has CreateBlogDto as values and strings as keys. @KaziAkibJaved

import { IsString, IsNotEmpty, IsOptional, IsObject } from 'class-validator';
export class CreateDynamicDataDto {
@IsString()
@IsNotEmpty()
title: string;
@IsObject()
@IsOptional()
data: { [key: string]: any }; // Using a dictionary type to allow dynamic key-value pairs
}

Try to implement it according to your need.

Thanks! It seems that the missing @IsObject decorator was making the data not go through, adding it solved the issue. Any idea how one would validate the dictionary?
